# Spring MVC Error: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a simple Spring MVC Project to display "Hello World" and it is working fine. Now, I want to add some css properties. I created a css folder inside WebContent and added a css file in it and added below line in my dispatcher servlet:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

Now I'm getting below errors on console:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringTest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

This is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringGradle</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>         
       </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>        
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Here is my Dispatcher servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pawan.controller" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And the JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<spring:url value="/css/myStyleCss.css" var="myStyleCss" />
<link href="${myStyleCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2 class="test">Welcome</h2><br>
<h3>${message}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Class:

```
package com.pawan.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView login() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        model.addObject("message", "Hello !!! First Spring Program");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Please help me in clearing my concepts.

Comment: Try to add _ location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/css/"_ . The name in mapping attribute is just dealing with the url not the folder structure and the name in location is the a phisycal place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Below line was missing in my dispatcher servlet:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```